# finding most informative image

Tags: matlab, pattern-matching, computer-vision

I have 1000 large images which mostly share similar features and one template (top images at below). My aim is to find the closest pattern to my template (bottom image) in these images. However, using all of those 1000 images and searching among all of them is not affordable. Therefore, I am looking for a method to decide which one of these 1000 images I should use for similarity calculation. In other words, which one is more informative.

Is there any solution?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide more information on the images. If there is a simple solution for what you're interested in it will have to be tailored to the images you are searching. Scale a good example down and include in your post. Interesting question ...

Comment: @DrSAR: I edited the question and added a picture to make it more clear.

Answer (score 1):

Consider [Scale Invariant Feature Transforms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scale-invariant_feature_transform). This still depends a bit on how well and how many features can be recognized in your template. But in principle this has the kind of strategy you are after:

- identify features in the template
- identify and populate a database of all features in all images
- search that database for the features previously identified in the template

This algorithm might be too permissive for your purposes since it will identify features even under most affine transforms (including scaling, rotation and partial occlusion) but on the other hand you might be able to find some pre-existing implementation of this such as [this one](http://www.vlfeat.org/~vedaldi/code/sift.html).